# Delayed jobs getting locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a RoR application that uses delayed jobs to run a large number of HTTP API calls, which are used to send bulk SMSs.

But, in unexpected scenarios, any one of these jobs is getting locked, not letting any of the jobs after it to be executed even if a fresh request is initiated. This continues until I set the `locked_by` value to `NULL`, followed by manually running these jobs, else the jobs are not processed. (I have the `locked_by` value in `delayed_jobs` table as `"<Server's Name>"`.)

Please guide me how to handle the delayed jobs in the scenarios described above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the parameters available to handle these things ? Like : 
`Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs, Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts, Delayed::Worker.max_run_time` ??

Comment: I can find Delayed::Job.destroy_failed_jobs and max_run_time. Please see [link] (http://pastebin.com/bws5k3TS)

Comment: can you check delayed job gem on github ? There would be proper documentation there.